# Show discount in Schema.org

Tags: html, schema.org, microdata, price

I have a product which has reduced price. I want to show both prices - original and discounted. Is there a way to mark this in Schema.org?

For now I have something similar:

```html
<ul class="productPriceList" itemprop="offers" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
     <li class="productPriceList">
         <div class="price red"><span class="" itemprop="price">4302</span>&nbsp;<span itemprop="priceCurrency" content="USD">$</span></div>
         <span class="price crossOut" itemprop="price">26890</span>&nbsp;<span itemprop="priceCurrency" content="USD">$</span>&nbsp;<span class="product-promo">84</span>%&nbsp;off
     </li>                  
</ul>
```

This shows as:

```
offers  
     @type: Offer
     price: 4302
     priceCurrency: USD 
     price: 26890
     priceCurrency: USD
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your current markup doesn’t convey which price is the old/new one. You shouldn’t use that.

You could use two [`PriceSpecification`](http://schema.org/PriceSpecification) items instead (as value for the [`priceSpecification`](http://schema.org/priceSpecification) property). With [`validFrom`](http://schema.org/validFrom) and [`validThrough`](http://schema.org/validThrough) you can specify the dates when the old price was valid and since when the new price is valid.

```html
<div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">

  <div itemprop="priceSpecification" itemscope itemtype="PriceSpecification">
    <s>$ <span itemprop="price">26890</span></s>
    <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="USD" />
    <meta itemprop="validThrough" content="…" />
  </div>

  <div itemprop="priceSpecification" itemscope itemtype="PriceSpecification">
    $ <span itemprop="price">4302</span>
    <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="USD" />
    <meta itemprop="validFrom" content="…" />
  </div>

</div>
```

(Note that the `span` element can’t have a `content` attribute in Microdata. I replaced it with a `meta` element.)

Comment: What if I don't have a validFrom and validThrough and it's not relevant for the project at all. Can I set today every time when the page renders?

Comment: @IrinaMarinova: Wasn’t there a date on which the discount started? If you have a date after which the original price was no longer valid, you could just use `validThrough` on the original price and omit `validFrom` on the new price (where consumers assume that the current valid price is the one that has no date-based restrictions).

Comment: It is not necessary to include `PriceSpecification` level. schema.org/Offer allows `price` and `priceCurrency` as `Offer` properties.

Comment: @AlexKudryashev: In that case you would have to provide *two* `Offer` items (with their own corresponding restrictions, e.g. again `validThrough`/`validFrom`). But I think semantically it’s the same offer, just with a changed price. So having one `Offer` item with two `PriceSpecification` items seems to be more appropriate to me than having two `Offer` items.

Comment: *Follow Up*: But using priceSpecification you can add `name` property like `standard price` and `discount price`

Comment: @AlexKudryashev Now that time has passed, what would the better option be? If it's better to write two `Offer` elements could you put that in an answer please?

Comment: @NobleUplift It should be a single offer with standardPrice and salesPrice and validThrough.

Comment: @AlexKudryashev Where in the schema is `salesPrice`? I checked `Offer` and `PriceSpecification`. https://schema.org/Offer